# how to tell nextjs to only bundle the words i used from dictionary file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, code-splitting

basically I have a dictionary file with hundreds of words in 3 different languages and this file is relatively big it's an extra 50 kb on each page

every word is exported in an object like this

```
export const Open_for_business = {
  eng: 'Open for business',
  ru: 'Открыт для бизнеса',
  uz: 'Xizmatlar doim bor!',
};
```

and when I import them I only import the ones I need for a specific page but nextjs still ends up adding the entire file to the build of the page in production,

any advice on how to only use the size of the ones I import?